# Smack 4 fails to connect to XMPP server due to SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, smack

I'm trying to use Smack 4.1.8 to connect to an XMPP server, but am encountering an SSLHandshakeException when connecting. If my understanding is correct, this is because Java can't verify that the XMPP server's certificate is trusted. (Perhaps due to missing certificates in the chain, or not having the root CA.)

However, the problem is that it seems the root CA is already trusted on my machine (OS X) – I can use Adium to connect to the XMPP server just fine. Additionally, I am able to connect to the XMPP server when I run my code on another computer (Windows).

Why is the root CA not trusted by Java on OS X? Where does Java look to find trusted CAs? (Is it different from what the OS and other applications, like Adium, would use?)

The code is rather simple:

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
configBuilder.setResource(RESOURCE_NAME);
configBuilder.setServiceName(domain);
configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required);
AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
connection.connect(); // <-- error is thrown after calling this
```

Full exception stacktrace:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1029)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:956)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:971)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPTCPConnection.java:769)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$1000(XMPPTCPConnection.java:140)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1022)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Were you able to determine if all intermediate certificates are sent by the server during the handshake? If the server is public, you can check this using SSL Labs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) or What's My Chain Cert? (https://whatsmychaincert.com/)

Comment: All intermediate certificates are being sent. There's (1) the server's certificate which is issued by (2) StartCom Class 2 Primary Intermediate Server CA which is issued by (3) StartCom Certification Authority.